# Firebase orderByChild equalTo hangs when no data

Tags: javascript, firebase

see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/237ur2tf/14/

```
coinref.orderByChild("uuid").equalTo("xx")...
```

Query works fine when there is a match in the database.
When there is no match, neither the callback nor error function is called.

Am I doing something wrong?... What would be the way around this?.

Many thanks.
Pat/

Answer (score 2):

That is the expected behavior. The relevant snippet from your fiddle is slightly longer:

```
// Get by child uuid AND uuid exists
coinsRef.orderByChild("uuid")
        .equalTo("4D4B2118-0435-439C-BA7C-99B9BD0DA7F4")
        .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
```

This code says that "when there is an (existing or new) child added to this query, call me with its snapshot". Since there is no child, the `child_added` event doesn't fire.

If you want to check *if there is a value*, you should use a `value` event:

```
// Get by child uuid AND uuid exists
coinsRef.orderByChild("uuid")
        .equalTo("4D4B2118-0435-439C-BA7C-99B9BD0DA7F4")
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("found Coin: 4D4B2118-0435-439C-BA7C-99B9BD0DA7F4");
```

If you want to do anything with the specific coin, you'll need to `forEach()` in the callback:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    console.log("The coin has value: "+child.val());
})
```

Is there any reason why you can't store the coins by their uuid? It sounds like that is already a universally unique identifies; so if it is possible to store them with that key, the lookup would be a lot cheaper:

```
coinsRef.child("4D4B2118-0435-439C-BA7C-99B9BD0DA7F4")
        .on('value', function(snapshot) {
    console.log("The coin has value: "+snapshot.val());
})
```

Comment: Right!  The solution is to use "value" to detect an invalid id.  snapshot returned value can be checked.  "child_added" does not trigger since there is no value.  There is a reason to not use the uuid as the key... but that's not the point here :)  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fran van Puffelen, What would be the equivalent for java?