# Firebase .orderByChild().equalTo().once().then() Promises when child doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, firebase-realtime-database

My API `/auth/login` endpoint takes a `req.body` like this:

```
{
  "email": "jacob@gmail.com",
  "password": "supersecretpassword"
}
```

At the endpoint, I make a reference to my Firebase database (`https://jacob.firebaseio.com/users`). I search through the data, and when I find one user with the email that matches `req.body.email`, I compare the password with the one stored in the database.

I followed the promise structure outlined [in this Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html).

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  const ref = db.ref('/users');

  ref.orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(req.body.email)
    .once('child_added')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      return snapshot.val();
    })
    .then(function (usr) {

      // Do my thing, throw any errors that come up

    })
    .catch(function (err) {

      // Handle my errors with grace

      return;
    });
});
```

If no child is found at `ref`, the function does not proceed (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078755/firebase-orderbychild-equalto-hangs-when-no-data)). I don't even get an error thrown.

My goal is to run code when no user is found with a certain email (i.e. no child is found at `ref` that satisfies `.equalTo(req.body.email)`), but not run the code if a user is found. No error is thrown when nothing is found.

I tried adding `return` statements at strategic points in the call to the database (at the end of my `.then()` promises) with the intention of breaking out of the endpoint entirely after the code was run. I then put code after the call to the database:

```
    .then(function (usr) {

      // Do my thing, throw any errors that come up

    })
    .catch(function (err) {

      // Handle my errors with grace

      return;
    });

  res.status(401)
    .json({
      error: 'No user found',
    )};

  return;
});
```

but this code is run whether the call to the database succeeds or not, since the call is asynchronous.

How do I react to this call to the database if it doesn't return anything *and* still use Firebase promises?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `child_added` event only fires if the query matches at least one of the keys under `users` and will fire multiple times if there are multiple matches.

You can use the `value` event instead - it will fire only once and its snapshot will contain all of the keys under `users` that matched or will have `value` of `null` if there are no matches:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  const ref = db.ref('/users');

  ref.orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(req.body.email)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      if (value) {
        // value is an object containing one or more of the users that matched your email query
        // choose a user and do something with it
      } else {
        res.status(401)
          .json({
            error: 'No user found',
          )};
      }
    });
});
```

Regarding handling of errors, you can wire up the promise and express error handling like this:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  const ref = db.ref('/users');

  ref.orderByChild('email')
    .equalTo(req.body.email)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      ...
    })
    .catch(next);
});
```